# How to disable Virtuemart2 default shipping

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have 2 shipping methods within Virtuemart & One Page Checkout (e-go & Fastways), and as a default on page load, "e-go" shipping is selected as a default!

I have tried everything to make "Fastways" the default shipping method; by modifying the list_order and id. But somehow "e-go" is always taking precedent?! Any clues as to how to prevent this?

ps: I've seen a post that makes a hack in virtuemart (but this isn't using One Page Checkout)...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the shipping method ordering. As Virtuemart shows the first one being selected. You will need to ordering of Shipping methods so that Fastways goes on top.

Comment: Have tried that, by adjusting the LIST_ORDER, and the index of the ID of the modules; neither works!